# Eclipse edit java files and run under original folder

Tags: java, eclipse

Although this seems an easy thing I'm not able to find the answer for it.

What I'd like to achieve is simple. I have a folder with java source files and I want to edit them using eclipse within a new project. But at the time of running the application I don't want eclipse to use the workspace project folder as "root", instead it should use the folder with the java source files.

The effect should be like opening the source files with a text editor directly and changing them, but instead this should be done through an eclipse project but still use the original folder to run the application.

I just want to have all the advantages that come from editing source files within an eclipse project instead of using something like notepad++.

I tried linking the source files and changing the relative path to the source directory but it doesn't work. When running the application it needs xml files which exist in the directory but because it's running "from" the eclipse project folder it doesn't find them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I really understand what you want to do, but sounds like you want to set the run configuration's working directory: Open 'Run Configurations', choose the class containing your main method (or create a new run configuration for that class first if it's not yet there), then specify the Working Directory on tab 'Arguments'.

Comment: I'll give it a shot. Will the binaries be sent to the arguments folder or to the workspace eclipse project folder?

Comment: closest correct answer...the binaries are still compiled to workspace folder and not the original directory but the external files which only exist in the original folder are reachable

Answer (score 1):

I do same with all my projects. What you need to do is :

1. Create workspace directory on different location than your source code.
2. Import your source code in your workspace directory. Here don't copy `source to your workspace`

**EDIT**

In Eclipse

1. Go to File->Switch Workspace->Other-> Type "new directory workspace" path, click OK. Eclipse will restart.
2. Go to File->Import->General-> Existing Projects into Workspace-> Next-> Select Root directory
3. Eclipse will list your project, select it.
4. Start editing and saving files.

Comment: Do you mean drag and drop the source files and choose the option link? not copy

Comment: I honestly don't understand how that would do what I want. I don't want to change my workspace. I want it to be the default one, which is where I also want to save my new project. But instead of having as the running path my workspace folder I want it to be the folder where the source files are(which are linked to the project). I just want to be able to edit the source files under an eclipse project but running should be done from where the source files are, in order to keep external file references, like .xml files, correct

Comment: The source files folder doesn't have an eclipse project...they are just source files being compiled through javac directly.
I want to have an eclipse project with those source files but instead of running them under the workspace directory, as  default, I want to do it under the original source folder where they actually are. Because there are a lot of external files in that folder I don't want to copy them to the workspace directory.

Answer (score 0):

Thought this does not directly answer your question, as an alternative to using Eclipse IDE for Java files try using Padclipse which is a text editor based on Eclipse.

> Padclipse is a light weight text editor based on Eclipse. The basic
>   product is composed of Eclipse RCP plus Text Editor, Compare and
>   Search facilities and their dependencies. A few additional third party
>   plug-ins are included as well.

Check it out **[here](http://padclipse.sourceforge.net/)**

Also, the default JDK on my system was a 64 bit because of which starting up padclipse failed. Create a padclipse.ini in the folder where you unzipped it in and put in the following contents :

```
-showsplash
-launcher
padclipse.exe
-name
Padclipse
--launcher.library
plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.0.0.v20070523\eclipse_1017a.dll
-startup
plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.0.v20070606.jar
-vm
C:\dev\jdk\1.5\1.5.0_21\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
```

Change `-vm` argument to point to the `java.exe` or `jvm.dll` of a 32 bit jdk.

Comment: What I want is under eclipse as I'm familiar with it

Comment: Padclipse is based on Eclipse !!

Comment: I don't want to have to install a new software to do that